# Binary reader with arduino blinking 8 leds

Tags: arduino-uno, led

I´m trying to insert a binary raw sequence (01010100, 01101000, 01100001) into Arduino. I would like to make 8-led group blink in a loop, showing with light each 8-group binary sequence when: 0=light off and 1=light on.

It´s possible to do this operation with Arduino-uno ?

Comment: i don't think binary is supported in arduino, but you could use bitwise operators with the decimal values of these binaries

Comment: You should be able to do what you are asking, however your question is not very clear.  Are you asking how you would turn on/off the LEDs based on the binary value of a variable, or how you would get the raw sequence into the Arduino/source code?  Or both?  How are you wanting to get the sequence into the Arduino?  Is it to be pre-scripted in the source code, stored on some external device (such as an SD card), input by a user from some other hardware (such as a keypad) or transmitted (either wirelessly or via a serial connection)?

Comment: @razzak: Binary not being supported by Arduino is the silliest statement I ever heard about this platform. Almost _everything_ inside the Arduino is binary. Decimal is only used for I/O, and only because we, humans, like it better that binary.

Comment: @EdgarBonet i was talking about using binary literals not the operations at the cpu level, you can not do `int x = 01001001;` in arduino. You can however use binary [special notation (formatter)](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/IntegerConstants) like `int x = B01001001;` which is not actual binary but rather a predefined decimal like doing `#define B01001001 73`.

Comment: Then, in your initial comment, you failed to make clear what you were talking about. The “B” notation is, _in actual practice_ not that different from “0x” for hex. Or even decimal, which is only a notation after all: you do not really care whether it is interpreted by the preprocessor or the compiler proper.

Answer (score 1):

You just prepend the number in binary with B e.g. B01100100 which is 100 in decimal

```
byte sequence[] = {
    B10000000,
    B01000000,
    B00100000,
    B00010000,
    B00001000,
    B00000100,
    B00000010,
    B00000001
}
```

And to check the n-th bit from the right in a number you do

```
boolean bit_set = number & (1 << (n - 1)) != 0;
```